# Chrome [VM] files create event handler in every load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I use asp.net razor and I load part of page in a partial view by Jquery load function. Part of script in the partial view is a JavaScript event like this:

```
$("#FormId").on("submit", function () {
     //doSomeThing..
     //ajax request ..
     $("ContainerDivId").load("UrlToAction"); //load partial view in ajax success function
});
```

The problem is event create by every load and bind to another handler in another chrome VM file so handler function call several times by click on submit button.

[image]

I solved the problem by a flag variable but I know there is a clean solution. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code that adds the event handler to remove the old one first:

```
$("#duplicateFacilityForm").off("submit").on("submit", function ...);
```